# Flutter device credentials saving and associated domains

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am so lost. I need some insight on what could be wrong.

I have 2 apps. Zandu and Zandu Admin. They are the client facing and the admin apps for my online marketplace.

The code uses flutter's AutofillGroup with email and password hints like so:

```
autofillHints: const[AutofillHints.email],
autofillHints: const[AutofillHints.password],
```

and this code to prompt the saving:

```
TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);
```

It works in the client app (Zandu), but not in the Admin app (Zandu Admin).

I am not sure what could be causing this. Any hints?

Could it be due to associated domains? Is that a prerequisite on Android as well?

Should i add this to my apple-app-site-association file?
I have one configured here at zandu.biz but not sure if it is valid or not.

```
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "BZZ4.biz.zandu.marketplaceclientmobile.ios", "BZZ4.biz.zandu.mobileadmin.ios"
        ]
    }
}
```